# Ajax : function is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I don't know why my code does not work onclick, but there is no pop up. The AJAX function var `phone` and `id` got data, but the AJAX did not. Is there anything wrong with the script? Does the AJAX need a jQuery library?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function clickButton() {
    var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
    var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "userDetaiAjax.php",
      data: {
        'phone': phone,
        'id': id
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        alert('Data Send');
        $('#msg').html(html);
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
</script>
<div class="col">
  <div class="form-group">
      <h6>
        <label>Name :</label>
        <?php echo $name ?>
      </h6>
      <h6>
        <label>Email :</label>
        <?php echo $email ?>
      </h6>
      <input type="" name="phone" id="phone">
      <input type="" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION[" staff_id "];?>" hidden>
      <h6>
        <label>Phone :</label>
        <?php echo $phone ?>
      </h6>
      <input type="submit" name="aa" value="submit2" onclick="return clickButton();">
    </form>
    <p id="msg"></p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

for the url

```
<?php 
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo 'success';
echo $phone;
echo $id;

$a='"USR_ID"';
$b='"phone"';
include 'conn.php';
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);

}

   $query = "update usr_web SET phone=:c1 WHERE usr_id=:c2";

              $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);

   oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":c1", $phone);
   oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":c2", $id);


                                 $result = oci_execute($stid);
                                 oci_free_statement($stid);
                                 oci_commit($conn);
                                  oci_close($conn);
                            echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: Yes, I think you need a jquery library because `$.ajax({})` is a jquery function

Comment: insert `type` in input fields

Comment: there is anything wrong for the code?

Comment: is url: userDetaiAjax.php OR url: userDetailAjax.php   L(el) before A ?

Comment: `type="hidden"` or `type="text"`

Comment: @DrMJ what did you mean? i already provide the url code

Comment: Why don't you add the `error` setting into your AJAX call and see if there's any error? Something like `success: function(html) {
        alert('Data Send');
        $('#msg').html(html);
      }, error : function (xhr, msg) { alert(xhr.status + ' - ' + msg); } `

Comment: try, put ajax at end of your html, and then try

Comment: @jens I am just asking if there is any spelling mistake in url ? userDetaiLAjax.php check if you missed L in word "Detail" script name ?

Comment: @DrMJ the spelling is right without L

Comment: After the success function. Add the error handler and console out the error                                                  
Success : function(html) {
        alert('Data Send');
        $('#msg').html(html);
      }, Error: function (data){.                     console.log(data)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U have error in your console:

> $ is not defined

Which mean u did not include jquery, so u should add this code after ajax include:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

U can chack your console errors with `F12 key` in browser and `tab Console`.

Answer (score 2):

When you open the console of your browser you should see an error message like "ReferenceError: $ is not defined". So it seems that $ is not part of core.js which you have loaded. Just load the full version (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js) and it should work.